# Fortify Error : "No rules file found"

Tags: java, fortify

When I run a Fortify analysis against a Java project I receive this error :

```
[warning]: No rules files found
[error]: No rules files found
```

Where can I configure the rules file ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319312/how-can-i-see-all-the-rules-of-fortify-secure-coding-rules

Comment: @lulyon I don't think that explains how to resolve this error >

Comment: That is OK, I'am just trying to offer a little related information.

Comment: I had to turn off VPN and change from office network to personal network in order to make it work with "fortifyupdate.cmd -acceptSSLCertificate" command.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The folder \Core\config\rules contains the rules files which can be dowloaded from update.fortify.com by invoking the command (on Windows):

```
bin\fortifyupdate.cmd
```

Answer (score 12):

To download the fortify rules files

1. Navigate to the *bin* folder of your fortify installation
2. Enter fortifyupdate.cmd.

If your network uses a proxy server, before running fortifyupdate.cmd specify your proxy server as follows

1. Navigate to the *bin* folder of your fortify installation
2. Enter scapostinstall
3. Enter 2 to select Settings
4. Enter 2 to select Proxy Server Host
5. Enter the name of the proxy server
6. Enter 3 to select Proxy Server Port.
7. Enter the proxy server's port number.
8. Exit and run fortifyupdate.cmd

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling fortify by connecting to client vpn resolved the issue.