# List of fortify rules

Tags: fortify

For documentation purpose I want to prepare a list of all rules HP fortify applies on a code.

For example, sonar provides a json web service (http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/rules/search?languages=java) which lists all the rules sonar applies on the code.

Is there any way I can find a list of all fortify rules applied on a piece of code?

I checked this post [How can I see all the rules of Fortify Secure Coding Rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319312/how-can-i-see-all-the-rules-of-fortify-secure-coding-rules) but I think the author of this post wanted to look at the code/implementation of each rule. I do not want to know how the rules are implemented. I want to simply know the list of rules what fortify applies on the code.

Answer (score 2):

Fortify has a list of the rules online. You can search [vulncat](https://vulncat.fortify.com/) by language. For example, here are all the [Java rules](https://vulncat.fortify.com/en/weakness?codelang=Java%2FJSP). On the left side, you can change the language to any of the supported ones to see the rules for that language.

Answer (score 0):

This is a proprietary implementation detail of Fortify SCA. They will probably not tell you how to obtain this information.

But try adding the arguments `-debug` and `-debug-verbose` and `-logfile` to your `-scan` command, and you may see some or all of the rules in the log file.